# Android app with READ_SMS permission worked on emulator but not with physical device

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions

I am creating an app with read_sms permission.it worked perfectly fine with emulator but when deployed on Samsung galaxy s5 with android 4.4.2 causing error.the app does not even start when tapped.it displays app isn't installed.

ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.project.searchandroid/.MainActivity } from null (pid=24876, uid=2000) requires android.permission.READ_SMS

ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1465)

ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1419)

ActivityManager: at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerNative.java:2367)

ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:680)
[2015-03-24 19:07:47 - SearchAndroid] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:270)

ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:47)
[2015-03-24 19:07:47 - SearchAndroid] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:76)

ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)

ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:301)

ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Please help me. i have project to complete. Thnx.

here is my manifest file

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project.searchandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
 
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
        <activity 
            android:name=".PreferenceActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity 
            android:name=".FilterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"/>
        <activity 
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.project.searchandroid.MainActivity">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: That stack trace does not line up with that manifest. The error you are getting is if you had `android:permission="android.permission.READ_SMS"` on the `<activity>` element for `MainActivity`.

Comment: i removed that attribute from the manifest then didn't check if its working or not.Any way thank you veru much :) @CommonsWare